# Check a string exists in the query response c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting a response from the select query and storing them in to the string list

```
        string abc = "123";
        List<string> numb = new List<string>();
        string selectQuery = "SELECT Number FROM NumberList;";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                numb.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
```

I am not sure how to check the string abc exists in numb. I dont want to use for loop for this because the count of records returned from query response is high. Is there any easy of checking if the 123 exists in the list or not.

Comment: `if (numb.Contains(reader.GetString(0))
{
    //yes, it contains!
}`

Comment: I need to check if numb contains string abc

Comment: if (numb.Contains(abc))

Comment: But why are you doing this at all? `SELECT Number FROM NumberList WHERE Number=123` will give you one record if 123 is in the database, and zero if it's not. Why read everything and then throw it away?

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
if (numb.Contains(abc)) 
{
   // List contains the string contained in variable abc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var s = reader.GetString(0);
    if (!numb.Contains(s))
    {
        numb.Add(s);
    }
}
```